# Why does my NodeJS Express app serve the entire website when sendFile() only contains path to one particular html file on the website

Tags: node.js, express

my directories are as follows

```
//SE-Metro-Q
...<other files>
...contact.html
//SE-Metro-Q-Private
...server.js
```

Each directory is a separate set of webpages in their own website, and from a webpage in SE-Metro-Q-Private, I am redirecting to a webpage in SE-Metro-Q in a get request.

I have the following middleware:

```
app.use("/contactForm", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../SE-Metro-Q')));
```

And then the route:

```
app.get('/contactForm', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('contact.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/../SE-Metro-Q') });
})
```

From what I understand when I go to /contactForm on the browser, it should only load contact.html, but instead it loads index.html from the SE-Metro-Q directory specified in the middleware above.

How can I modify it to only load contact.html?

Comment: Probably has to do with __dirname being / and "/../SE-Metro-Q" making it go back a folder

Comment: SE-Metro-Q directory is in a parent directory from server.js so I had to set the filepath like that. Sorry I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`express.static()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) serves a *directory* of static files; you've mounted your local path `/../SE-Metro-Q` to the `/contactForm` route. As such, Express will serve the *entire* directory off the `/contactForm` route.

If you want to only serve one file, remove your `express.static()` route entirely and explicitly respond with the file you want to serve on that route, just as you have in your second snippet.